# 4G Cradle Wimax & Huawei M358 modem Drivers

Tags: usb, huawei

**ENGLISH TRANSLATION**

Hi from Costa Rica. There is a company here that provides wireless internet service using an USB modem. It also uses an amplified antenna or cradle wimax. Both from the same brand, Huawei, which are 4G and not 3G like the Huawei modems that sell ICE and Kolbi.

I wanted to know how to obtaind and install their respective drivers to have both devices functioning.

Thanks you.

**ORIGINAL**

Saludos desde Costa Rica. Aqui hay una empresa proveedora de servicios de internet inalámbrico vía módem USB...usa ademas una antena amplificadora o cradle wimax. Ambos de la marca Huawei.y son 4G...no 3G como los módems huawei que vende el ICE y Kolbi.

Quería conocer donde y como obtener los driver o poner a funcionar esos dispositivos. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

From Venezuela I tested 3 types of Huawei and one type of 4G in Ubuntu 12.04. I can verify that they work out of the box. Typically in Ubuntu there is no need to install 99% of the drivers for most devices. In this case, just to test them out, I connected them to the USB port. Ubuntu detected them correctly and even configured them automatically. I had internet in a couple of seconds after that.

I also have the same M358 you mention and it works correctly. Again in the 12.04 version since it is the one I am using (Don`t know what version you have or if it works on previous versions).

For the Wimax part, it is in my understanding that Ubuntu has had support for Wimax for several versions. Since 10.04 (2 years ago) I think.

You can test this out by first updating your version of Ubuntu to the latest and then connecting your Modem via USB. The network manager icon in the top right should start changing and begin configuring your device.

ESPANOL

Hola Miguel, desde Venezuela te puedo decir que probe 3 tipos de Huawei y uno en 4G. los probe en Ubuntu 12.04. Pude verificar que funcionaron perfectamente sin tener que instalar o configurar algo adicional. Tipicamente en Ubuntu, en el 99% de las veces, no tendras que instalar ningun tipo de drviers o realizar configuraciones complicadas. En este caso simplemente conecte via USB el modem y Ubuntu me lo detecto y configuro automaticamente. Tuve internet luego de un par de segundos. Todo perfecto.

Yo tambien tengo el M358 que mencionas y trabaja perfectamente. Claro vuelvo a mencionar, en la 12.04 ya que no se que version utilizas o si funcionaria en una version anterior de Ubuntu.

Por la parte de WiMax, tengo entendido que Ubuntu ha soportado esta tecnologia desde hace unas versiones atras. Creo que desde la 10.04 si no me equivoco.

Puedes probar esto simplemente actualizando Ubuntu y luego conectando tu modem via usb. El icono del network manager en la parte superior derecha deberia cambiar y comenzar a configurar tu modem.